# Problemas al leer DOM o HTML de pagina activa con extension de google

Tags: javascript, extensión-google-chrome, extensiones

Mira, lo que yo necesito es que cuando yo haga click aqui:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Y dentro de ahi aqui: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](que es el html de abajo)
Me lea el DOM de la pagina que este actualmente activa. Es decir, quiero recopilar los datos del DOM, recabar el html, y intenpretar y modificar eso.

POR SI NO SE ENTIENDE CON FOTOS:

***La cosa es que quiero que cuando toques un botón lea el código html de la tab o pestaña en la que se a accionado. Por ejemplo, cuando le de al botn de test, y este en la pagina de gmail, me envíe un action() en js(lo de comprobar que es gmail lo hago yo)
Asique resumiendo, necesito leer el DOM o html de una pestaña activa cuando cliques el boton de la extensión.***

Y aqui el html del display que veis:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/5/minty/bootstrap.css">
    
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" style="width:300px; height: 200px;">
        <div class="container" >
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleTextarea" class="form-label mt-4">Insert initials</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="initials_text" rows="1"></textarea>
            </div>      
        </div>
        <div class="container" style="margin-top:15px;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <button type="button" id="force" class="btn btn-primary">Force</button>
                    <button type="button" id="test" class="btn btn-primary">Test</button>
                    <button type="button" id="parar" class="btn btn-primary"> Parar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="handler.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.